# c++ split a file into records when blank space is found?

Tags: c++, readfile, coredump

I have a file like this

```
2.7388  0 2.4670
3.6384  1 24.5927
8.7844  0 10.6871
11.2892 0 2.6507
19.6054 1 16.8974
25.8811 0 8.0084
```

For example i'll take the first row `2.7388  0 2.4670` . Im trying to accomplish something like the following

```
2.7388 = double x
0      = int y
2.4670 = double z
```

My attempt

```
struct fileReader{
double x;
int y;
double z;
};

std::vector<fileReader> afileReader(std::string fileName) {

  std::vector<fileReader> readtheFile;
  std::ifstream List;
  std::string line;
  List.open(fileName);
 char delimiter = ' '; //delimiter added

  while (std::getline(List, line))
  {
    line.pop_back();
    std::string token;
    std::istringstream ss(line);
    fileReader afileReader;

    std::getline(ss, token,delimiter);
    afileReader.x = std::stod(token); //change from stoi to stod
 
    std::getline(ss, token,delimiter);
    afileReader.y = std::stoi(token);

    std::getline(ss, token,delimiter);
    afileReader.z = std::stod(token); //change from stoi to stod
    readtheFile.push_back(std::move(afileReader));
  }

for(fileReader x: readtheFile) {
      std::cout << x.x;
      std::cout << x.y;
      std::cout << x.z;
  }
  return readtheFile;
  passengerList.close();

}
```

When i run this from main running a line `afileReader("file.txt")` . I get the following error

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
  what():  stod //error changed
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Im not sure why im getting an error for stoi as its the correct conversion method to convert the int value to the string(as token is a string)

To refer back to the question though I wish to split the record when a blank space is hit. So refering back to the previous example of `2.7388  0 2.4670` , when `2.7388` is read its assigned to variable `x`, when `0`  is read its assigned to varible `y` and `2.4670` is assigned to variable `z`

Comment: Why are you reading it as string? Why not simply do `file >> x >> y >> z`?

Comment: @brc-dd One problem is that the OP for some reason attempts to read what looks like floating-point numbers into integer variables.

Comment: @davylang Why do you try to read floating-point numbers (like e.g. `2.7388`) into integers? That conversion will truncate the value from `2.7388` to `2`.

Comment: As for one problem with the current code, please read more about [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) and think a little more how to use it to split on specific characters rather than newline (which is what you're doing right now).

Comment: @brc-dd Ive changed my code to accompany your sugguestions(see edited question above) However now i get the same error but for stod not stoi

Comment: @brc-dd still get the same error. Are you sugguesting I just do List >> x >> y >> z

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Recommended) More direct way to do this :

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Data {
  double x;
  int y;
  double z;
};

std::vector<Data> fileReader(std::string fileName) {

  std::vector<Data> result;
  std::ifstream file(fileName);

  Data data;

  while (file >> data.x >> data.y >> data.z)
    result.push_back(data);

  for (auto &&i : result)
    std::cout << i.x << ' ' << i.y << ' ' << i.z << '\n';

  return result;
}

int main() { fileReader("test.txt"); }
```

[Sample Run](https://wandbox.org/permlink/K4de6yDk9DCYQZ2Y)

---

Problems with your original code :

1. `fileReader::x` and `fileReader::z` were not floating-type numbers.
2. `' '` was not being passed as delimiter in call to `std::getline`.
3. Inconsistent spacing in the file you were reading. ([FIX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20045810/11613622))
4. For some strange reason you were doing `line.pop_back()`;
5. [Cause of certain warning] You weren't returning anything from `afileReader()` (non-void function).

Fixed code :

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <istream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

struct fileReader {
  double x;
  int y;
  double z;
};

std::vector<fileReader> afileReader(std::string fileName) {

  std::vector<fileReader> readtheFile;
  std::ifstream List(fileName);
  std::string line;

  while (std::getline(List, line)) {

    std::string token;
    std::istringstream ss(line);
    fileReader afileReader;

    ss >> std::ws;
    std::getline(ss, token, ' ');
    afileReader.x = std::stod(token);

    ss >> std::ws;
    std::getline(ss, token, ' ');
    afileReader.y = std::stoi(token);

    ss >> std::ws;
    std::getline(ss, token);
    afileReader.z = std::stod(token);

    readtheFile.push_back(std::move(afileReader));
  }

  for (auto &&i : readtheFile)
    std::cout << i.x << ' ' << i.y << ' ' << i.z << '\n';

  return readtheFile;
}

int main() { afileReader("test.txt"); }
```